# IQueryable execute expression against underlying QueryProvider

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects, iqueryable

Could you help me understand why the following code throws an exception during execution?

```
IQueryable<TestDto> data = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(i => new TestDto()
{
        Id = i,
        Name = (i%1000).ToString()
}).AsQueryable();
var test = data.Provider.Execute<TestDto>(data.Expression);
```

It is very strange to me, that query provider is unable to execute expression when both QueryProvider and Expression are taken from the same IQueryable instance!

**Edit:** Thrown exception is ArgumentException considering parameter 'expression' of method Execute.

Comment: What do you expect `data.Expression` to be in your case ? What is the error you're getting ?

Comment: In your case `data.Expression` is expected to return multiple `TestDto` objects, but you are passing `TestDto` as `TResult` (single item). Try passing an expression that returns a single `TestDto` (whose return type is `TestDto`).

Comment: @YacoubMassad Thank you very much. That is exactly the case :)

Answer (score 0):

`Execute`: Executes the specified expression on the underlying data source. `data.Expression` is a `ConstantExpression` (Holding the values).

You need to pass to `Execute` a valid expression tree, e.g. A `filter` predicate, or a `Projection` that can be further interpreted by the provider.

**Below is a valid usage:**

```
IQueryable<Item> data = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(i => new Item()
{
        SomeProperty = i
}).AsQueryable();

Expression<Func<Item, bool>> expression = x => x.SomeProperty > 50;

var obj = data.Provider.Execute(expression);
```